# powershell write-host individual file name from get-content list

Tags: powershell

How can i get the individual filename to show in the write-host output? right now it just leaves it blank. If i just leave it as $line and not $line.filename it just lists the wildcard string the file references such as file*.dar .

```
     $remotePath = "C:\folder\"
     $lines = Get-Content "file.txt"

     foreach ($line in $lines) 
     {
        Write-Host "Downloading $($line.Filename) to C:\folder\ ..."
        $session.GetFiles($line, $remotePath).Check()
        $dt = Get-Date 
        Add-Content $log "$dt : Downloading $($line.Filename) to C:\folder.."
```

Comment: With Get-Content you'll get .. content - not objects like you do with Import-Csv and headers in the file. So there is no `.Filename` property.

Comment: To spell out what @LotPings is implying: use `$line` by itself inside your loop - it represents a line from your input file (as a string), and presumably that line contains the filename of interest. If that solves your problem, can I suggest you delete your question? It is unlikely to benefit future readers. If it doesn't solve your problem, please add clarifications to your question.

Comment: Ok maybe i wasn't clear enough .. i am already using it with just $line but that doesn't do what i need. i am not that familiar with powershell so i'm not sure if there is another way or not. i am using a list of wildcards to download files from an FTP server . i would like to be able to log the actual file name that is downloaded. currently like i indicated i can only get it to show the wildcard filename or be blank.